# how to get unique values in Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've 3 models:-

```
class Shipment(models.Model):
    job_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = True, db_index = True)

class ShipmentBagSealMapping(models.Model):
    bag_seal = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default = 'open')
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = True, db_index = True)
    shipment_id = models.ForeignKey('Shipment', related_name = 'bags')

class ShipmentPPTLMapping(models.Model):
    pptl_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = True)
    shipment_id = models.ForeignKey('Shipment', related_name = 'pptls')
```

**I want to fetch the count of those bags which are closed.**

Initially I have the `pptl_id`. So, I get the `shipment_id` from `ShipmentPPTLMapping` model, and then query the `ShipmentBagSealMapping` model with `shipmen_id`.

Here is what I have done:-

bags_closed = len(Shipment.objects.filter(bags_*status*_exact = 'close', bags_*time*_range = [start_time,end_time],pptls__pptl_id__exact = pptls.pptl_id))

The problem is since each bag can have multiple shipments, hence currently as per my query I'm able to get all the count of the shipments which are closed. I want to add another filteration like `bags_value = distinct`

something like

```
bags_closed = len(Shipment.objects.filter(bags__status__exact = 'close', bags__time__range = [start_time,end_time],pptls__pptl_id__exact = 147)).**bags_seal = distinct**
```

**Question2**

Also, I need to get the `last_bagged_on` parameter which gives me the time of the last bag which was closed. Obviously this field will be fetched from `ShipmentBagSealMapping` model, but my current object is of model `Shipment` .

**How would I get the last bag closed?**

Something like this:-

```
last_bagged_on  = Shipment.objects.filter(bags__status__exact = 'close', bags__time__range = [start_time,end_time],pptls__pptl_id__exact = pptls.pptl_id)[0].**bags_time**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1st

len(queryset) is a bad way to count on objects. Use `.count()` instead

```
bags_closed = Shipment.objects.filter(bags__status__exact='close', 
                                      bags__time__range=[start_time,end_time],
                                      pptls__pptl_id__exact = 147)\
                              .distinct('bags').count()
```

### 2nd

```
last_bagged_on = ShipmentBagSealMapping.objects.filter(
    status__exact='close',
    time__range=[start_time,end_time],
    shipment_id__pptls__pptl_id__exact=pptls.pptl_id)[0]
```

If you're using Django 1.6, you should use last_bagged_on = ShipmentBagSealMapping...first() instead of `[0]`

Comment: Well learned something new today, `first()` and `count()`. Thanks. But when I use distinct it throws an error saying `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend` What is it ?

Comment: I want distinct `bag_seal`'s. Should it be `.distinct('bags__bag_seal')`. Although tried with this as well. Didn't worked.

Comment: `.values_list('bags__bag_seal', flat=True).distinct())` worked. Thanks.

Comment: 2 queries:- 1) Why `count` and `first` are better than `len` and `[0]` respectively?

Comment: 2) The way you wrote `shipment_id__pptls__pptl_id__exact=pptls.pptl_id` was amazing. How did you applied 3 relations in one-query? I'm little weak in spanning relationships between 2 or more models. Please explain / guide me to a link where I can read on them. Thaks

Comment: @user1162512 `count` becomes the `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM` sql query which is much faster then `SELECT * FROM` and then counting on objects. `first` limiting query so it's faster too. If you use `distinct()` on field, this field must appear in `values()`